# When to execute REFRESH TABLE my_table in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Consider a code;

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc._
 import org.apache.spark.sql._

 val path = ...
 val dataFrame:DataFramew = ...

 val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sparkContext)
 dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")
 val results = hiveContext.sql(s"select * from my_table")
 results.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("my_column").format("orc").save(path)
 hiveContext.sql("REFRESH TABLE my_table")
```

This code is executed twice with same path but different dataFrames. The first run is successful, but subsequent rise en error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://somepath/somefile.snappy.orc
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

I have tried to clean up cache, invoke `hiveContext.dropTempTable("tableName")` and all have no effect. When to call `REFRESH TABLE tableName` before, after (other variants) to repair such error?

Comment: `hiveContext.refreshTable("my_table")` or `spark.catalog.refreshTable("my_table")` refreshes the table.

Comment: But when to invoke? After just after write operation?

Answer (score 7):

You can run `spark.catalog.refreshTable(tableName)` or `spark.sql(s"REFRESH TABLE $tableName")` just before the write operation. I had same problem and it fixed my problem.

```
spark.catalog.refreshTable(tableName)
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto(tableName)
```

Comment: The above solution only works if the table is not updated between the above 2 statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can either **refresh the table** (code) name or **restart the cluster**

```py
spark.sql("refresh TABLE schema.table")
```

> It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can
> explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE
> tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame
> involved. If Delta cache is stale or the underlying files have been
> removed, you can invalidate Delta cache manually by restarting the
> cluster.